# how to stop win7 pro/64bit remotedesktop title from showing remote IP plus my secret port number

Tags: windows-7, networking, remote-desktop

Fact: Win7 shows both IP & port number as the upper left of title of MSTSC screen.

Issue: This defeats the purpose of hiding the port number (not 3389).

This holds regardless I am using a RDP file or not.

Is there anyway to stop windows7 from showing IP/PORT#? How?

"MSTSC /?" shows no "/title=HOME" option
thanks

Comment: You do understand your port isn't hidden. Even a basic port scan from the outside would be able to determine that port was open.  See for yourself by using [Shields Up](https://www.grc.com/shieldsup)

Comment: Goal is not to have win7 broadcast to bystanders.

Comment: i can 'hide' my IP from MSTSC by alias in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the following settings in your `default.rdp` file, which will allow you to hide the connection bar, but only when in full screen mode:

```
pinconnectionbar:i:0
displayconnectionbar:i:0
```

If the entries are not there, add them. If they are, just ensure the numeric value is 0. If you make changes, you must restart the computer. One thing: When login in, the banner will display the information. Once you're logged in, the connection bar will appear briefly and then disappear. It won't appear if you hover the mouse on the upper middle section of the screen, so keep that in mind.

For a more detailed overview of the available settings, [check this informative page](http://www.donkz.nl/files/rdpsettings.html) from the author of [Remote Desktop Plus](http://www.donkz.nl/). Haven't used the software, but it does say that "You can set your own title bar text and specify your own icon." May want to consider that if the solution provided here won't cut it. :-)

Comment: i made the changes to my default.rdp on the client side & rebooted; same issue remains: host+port# appear in upper left corner.  thanks for the informative links.

Comment: @yule Sorry that didn't work for you. May have to give Remote Desktop Plus a try. It does have a `/title` flag, which should solve your issue.